# How to set a column value into null in select query in oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle19c

I want to select a column value which is equal to a specific page item value and select the other values as null.
The main table data is the following:

| id | first_numbers | second_numbers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1112 | 2222 |
| 1 | 3434 | 1112 |

The value of first_numbers=1112 is equal to :p4_number=1112 page item so the expected result which I want is:

| id | first_numbers | second_numbers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1112 | null |
| 1 | null | 1112 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CASE` expression:

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (id, first_numbers, second_numbers) as
  2    (select 1, 1112, 2222 from dual union all
  3     select 2, 3434, 1112 from dual
  4    )
```

Query itself:

```
  5  select id,
  6    case when first_numbers  <> &&P4_NUMBER then null else first_numbers  end first_numbers,
  7    case when second_numbers <> &&P4_NUMBER then null else second_numbers end second_numbers
  8  from test;
Enter value for p4_number: 1112

        ID FIRST_NUMBERS SECOND_NUMBERS
---------- ------------- --------------
         1          1112
         2                         1112

SQL>
```

As you use Apex, you'd use bind (instead of substitution) variable, i.e.

```
... case when first_numbers  <> :P4_NUMBER then
                                ^
                                |
                              this
```

Comment: Thank you Littlefoot your answer solved my problem.